# Is it possible to measure distance with signal strength?

Tags: rf

Is it possible to measure the distance between two devices by using RF signal strength if the devices have no obstructions between them?  If so then can 2 or 3 be used to get distance and direction?

How accurate could it be?

Comment: Yes. Accurate? Depends. Time of flight would be a more accurate technique.

Comment: What do you mean by time of flight?  Please elaborate, thanks.

Comment: Time of flight is measuring the time it takes the signal to travel. UWB is a recent technology that uses this technique.

Comment: Similar like how radar works, except the receiver doesn't need setup.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to measure the distance between two devices by using RF signal strength if the devices have no obstructions between them? If so then can 2 or 3 be used to get distance and direction?

It is theoretically possible to measure distance between two devices using the signal strength of an RF signal. However, that is not a common approach, and it is likely to be impractical.

You mention "obstacles" and that is one problematic area.

Another problem area is that no antenna is perfectly omni-directional. Changes in antenna orientation will affect signal reception, which in turn may be wrongly interpreted as changes in distance. This may be overcome by adding more transmitters.

Yet another problem area is calibration. It is not insurmountable, may not be terribly easy either.

A more practical way to triangulate position, I think, is to have the transmitters sending synchronized pulses or modulations, and comparing the time/phase differences received. This approach is immune to changes in the amplitude due to antenna orientations and attenuation due to obstacles. This is also the principle upon which GPS works.

Comment: I believe that GPS is accurate to a few feet, I was looking for something better than that.  The speed of the signal in a more localized close ranged system I think would pose a major problem, there would not be enough distance for the processor to calculate any difference.  I was thinking more of a short 20 feet or less distance.

Comment: @MGrambihler:  Differential GPS can measure differences of centimeters, even using equipment available to civilians.

Comment: I will need to look into that some time (Differential GPS), do you know if it is expensive, require special equipment?

Comment: RTK (Real-time kinematic), when added on to a GPS receiver, is accurate to 1 or 2 cm. There are subscriptions (using an established RTK system), or, you can set up your own RTK system.

Comment: As @MathKeepsMeBusy suggests, measuring time/phase differences are far more accurate than signal strength. Look into ultrawideband (UWB) technology. There are chips and modules operating in the 5-10 GHz range that can provide accuracies of 10-30 cm.

Comment: @MGrambihler I think you're stating the same, but I'd like to stress that GPS doesn't do localization based on signal strength at all. (it feels important to not confuse future readers.) In any multipath environment, localization becomes very complicated to provably impossible to do reliably.

Comment: By the way, GPS doesn't do *triangulation*, it doesn't care about *angles*. It does differential *quadrilateration*; i.e. it calculates the distances to four satellites